# '\DeclareAcroListStyle' has been removed

Tags: acro

When I compile the following, once working MWE I do now get the error

```
! Package acro Error: The command \DeclareAcroListStyle has been removed.
```

Seems as if the package `acro` has been updated, however I couldn't find any record regarding `\DeclareAcroListStyle`. Does anyone know how it is done now?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\myitemwidth
\setlength\myitemwidth{5em}

\newlist{listabbrev}{description}{1}
\setlist[listabbrev]{
    labelindent = 0pt,
    labelsep    = 0pt,
    leftmargin  = \myitemwidth,
    labelwidth  = \myitemwidth,
    format      = \normalfont
    }

\DeclareAcroListStyle{styleabbrev}{list}{list = listabbrev}

\acsetup{list/template  = styleabbrev,
     list/heading   = chapter*,
     list/name      = Abkürzungen
     }

\DeclareAcronym{EEG}{
  short = EEG,
  long  = Erneuerbare-Energien-Gesetz,
}

\DeclareAcronym{dbms}{
  short = DBMS,
  long  = Database Management System,
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms
\acuseall

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

I would like to obtain the following result:

[image]

Comment: This command seems te be replaced with `\NewAcroTemplate[list]`, see section 23.5 of the `acro` [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf) on page 41.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the note! Unfortunately I don't find a solution to get the desired result (see image). Do you or anyone else have an idea how to get there? If I exchange `\DeclareAcroListStyle{styleabbrev}{list}{list = listabbrev}` with `\NewAcroTemplate[list]{styleabbrev}` it simply won't print anything regarding the abbreviations... clearly there is something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With version 3 of `acro` the way the list styles (now called templates) are defined has changed completely – this happened to make the whole process more flexible and more customisable. The drawback is that it is not compatible with the way it was done in version 2. Just renaming the command will not do as you have discovered.

Quite some part of the manual describes how templates can be defined and modified. In your case it is actually not very difficult to adapt the layout you had:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\myitemwidth
\setlength\myitemwidth{5em}

\newlist{listabbrev}{description}{1}
\setlist[listabbrev]{
    labelindent = 0pt,
    labelsep    = 0pt,
    leftmargin  = \myitemwidth,
    labelwidth  = \myitemwidth,
    format      = \normalfont
    }

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{styleabbrev}{%
  \let\description\listabbrev
  \let\enddescription\endlistabbrev
  \UseAcroTemplate[list]{description}[0]%
}

\acsetup{
  list/template  = styleabbrev,
  list/heading   = chapter*,
  list/name      = Abkürzungen
}

\DeclareAcronym{EEG}{
  short = EEG,
  long  = Erneuerbare-Energien-Gesetz,
}

\DeclareAcronym{dbms}{
  short = DBMS,
  long  = Database Management System,
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms
\acuseall

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The layout in the picture you posted is a little different. The following code demonstrates how a template based on a `longtable` could be defined which simulates this layout:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\newlength\abbrevwidth
\setlength\abbrevwidth{6em}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{styleabbrev}{%
  \AcroNeedPackage{array,longtable}%
  \acronymsmapF{%
    \AcroAddRow{%
      \acrowrite{short}%
      \acroifT{alt}{/}\acrowrite{alt}%
      &
      \acrowrite{list}%
      \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{ (}%
      \acrowrite{foreign}%
      \acroifallT{foreign,extra}{, }%
      \acrowrite{extra}%
      \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{)}%
      \acropagefill
      \acropages
        {\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}
        {\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
      \tabularnewline
    }
  }{\AcroRerun}
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \par\noindent
  \begin{longtable}{@{}p{\abbrevwidth}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\abbrevwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
    \bfseries Abkürzung & \bfseries Erläuterung \endhead
    \AcronymTable
  \end{longtable}
}

\acsetup{
  list/template  = styleabbrev,
  list/heading   = chapter*,
  list/name      = Abkürzungsverzeichnis
}

\DeclareAcronym{EEG}{
  short = EEG,
  long  = Erneuerbare-Energien-Gesetz,
}

\DeclareAcronym{dbms}{
  short = DBMS,
  long  = Database Management System,
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms
\acuseall

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!